# How to intentionally cause a fatal error in PHP script?

Tags: php, crash

I want script to stop being executed at the point of the crash, while not to exhaust the memory or otherwise crash the server.

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: use php die(); it will stop executing

Comment: Error, I want it to die from a fatal error. I would like to see how the output is affected by a fatal error, if it just dies, a lot of other methods would be invoked with 'die' I suppose.

Comment: Weird requirement. Why you need this?

Comment: I want my script to have no more than one instance running at a time, and I locked a file: flock($fplock, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)   to check for concurrency. I want to see if the file will be unlocked when a fatal error occurs.  @Tushar

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
trigger_error("Oops!", E_USER_ERROR);
```

Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php

E_USER_ERROR is pretty much equal to E_ERROR, which is a [fatal runtime error](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php).

Comment: It won't be fatal if you use set_error_handler().  See my response below.

Answer (score 16):

Bit late but this is a guaranteed natural fatal error:

Call an undefined function, eg:

```
noSuchFunction();
```

Or if you want this to be executed when you are in 'test' mode only, then put it into an eval

```
if($isTestMode==1){
  eval("noSuchFunction();");
}
```

Note: With the trigger_error() function the problem is that if you are using set_error_handler() it ceases to be fatal - your error handler will decide what to do with it.